# MySQL Query for availability of employees

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table of employees who can all work in multiple sections. However, once a section is booked for the date/s they are not available to be be booked in the other sections for that date

Employee table is **Employees**

```
id_resources    id_sections EmployeeName    Section
28                25          Mark          Section Two
28                26          Mark          Section Three
28                28          Mark          Section Four
28                29          Mark          Section Five
28                53          Mark          Section Six
28                64          Mark          Section Seven
28                74          Mark          Section Eight
28                76          Mark          Section Nine
29                30          Blair         Section One
29                47          Blair         Section Two
29                49          Blair         Section Three
30                82          Sam           Section One
30                25          Sam           Section Two
30                28          Sam           Section Three
30                29          Sam           Section Four
31                18          David         Section Eleven
31                19          David         Section One
31                22          David         Section Two
31                25          David         Section Three
```

Then my Booking table is **Bookings**

```
id_resources    id_sections startdate   enddate
28                 25      2016-09-09   2016-09-09
28                 26      2016-09-20   2016-09-20
28                 28      2016-10-17   2016-10-17
30                 82      2016-10-18   2016-10-18
30                 25      2016-10-28   2016-10-28
29                 30      2016-11-02   2016-11-02
29                 47      2016-11-07   2016-11-07
29                 49      2016-11-01   2016-11-01
29                 58      2017-01-09   2017-01-09
```

So the issue I have is getting an employee to be:

*A.) not available for all sections if one section is booked for a day

 B.) showing an employee as available when a date range is selected and there are no bookings for that range.*

I can get part **A**, but not part **B**.

```
Select *
FROM employees
LEFT JOIN bookings on employees.id_resources = bookings.id_resources
WHERE
   (Select..... and i get lost here
```

Again thank you for any help!

-Lee

Comment: Can i ask why are you using id_resources instead of id_sections?

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like that :

```
SELECT employees.*
FROM employees
    LEFT OUTER JOIN bookings 
    ON employees.id_resources = bookings.id_resources 
        AND (
        (startdate BETWEEN $start_range AND $end_range)
        OR 
        (enddate BETWEEN $start_range AND $end_range)
        )
WHERE bookings.id_resources IS NULL
```

Quick explanation : We use LEFT OUTER JOIN ... WHERE ... IS NULL as exclusion. [This post](https://www.xaprb.com/blog/2005/09/23/how-to-write-a-sql-exclusion-join/) might help you

**Edit :** When you use LEFT OUTER JOIN as exclusion, **first**, you have to think at the opposite of your goal. Here, it will be *find a user that has a booking between two dates*. To do so, You will have a query like this one :

```
SELECT employees.*
FROM employees
    INNER JOIN bookings 
    ON employees.id_resources = bookings.id_resources 
        AND (startdate BETWEEN $start_range AND $end_range)
        AND (enddate BETWEEN $start_range AND $end_range)
```

Then you do the opposite.